# how to get the json response for a product url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape product information from https://www.walmart.com/. I am trying to do it in two stages.

1. Get search result products for a word
2. Get each product data by going to the product url.

```
import requests
import json
data= {
   
   "query":"query Browse( $query:String $page:Int $prg:Prg! $facet:String $sort:Sort $catId:String! $max_price:String $min_price:String $module_search:String $affinityOverride:AffinityOverride $ps:Int $ptss:String $beShelfId:String $fitmentFieldParams:JSON ={}$fitmentSearchParams:JSON ={}$rawFacet:String $seoPath:String $trsp:String $fetchMarquee:Boolean! $fetchSkyline:Boolean! $additionalQueryParams:JSON ={}){search( query:$query page:$page prg:$prg facet:$facet sort:$sort cat_id:$catId max_price:$max_price min_price:$min_price module_search:$module_search affinityOverride:$affinityOverride additionalQueryParams:$additionalQueryParams ps:$ps ptss:$ptss trsp:$trsp _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){query searchResult{...BrowseResultFragment}}contentLayout( channel:\"WWW\" pageType:\"BrowsePage\" tenant:\"WM_GLASS\" version:\"v1\" searchArgs:{query:$query cat_id:$catId _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId prg:$prg}){modules{...ModuleFragment configs{...on EnricherModuleConfigsV1{zoneV1}__typename...on _TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchSortFilterModuleConfigs{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPillsModuleConfigs{moduleSource pillsV2{...PillsModuleFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchFitmentModuleConfigs{fitments( fitmentSearchParams:$fitmentSearchParams fitmentFieldParams:$fitmentFieldParams ){...FitmentFragment sisFitmentResponse{...BrowseResultFragment}}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWStoreSelectionHeaderConfigs{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWBreadcrumbConfigs{_rawConfigs}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSponsoredProductCarouselConfigs{_rawConfigs}...PopularInModuleFragment...CopyBlockModuleFragment...BannerModuleFragment...HeroPOVModuleFragment...InlineSearchModuleFragment...MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchMarquee)...SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchSkyline)...HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment}}...LayoutFragment pageMetadata{location{postalCode stateOrProvinceCode city storeId}pageContext}}seoBrowseMetaData( id:$catId facets:$rawFacet path:$seoPath facet_query_param:$facet _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){metaTitle metaDesc metaCanon h1}}fragment BrowseResultFragment on SearchInterface{title aggregatedCount...BreadCrumbFragment...DebugFragment...ItemStacksFragment...PageMetaDataFragment...PaginationFragment...RequestContextFragment...ErrorResponse modules{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}pills{...PillsModuleFragment}}}fragment ModuleFragment on TempoModule{name version type moduleId schedule{priority}matchedTrigger{zone}}fragment LayoutFragment on ContentLayout{layouts{id layout}}fragment BreadCrumbFragment on SearchInterface{breadCrumb{id name url}}fragment DebugFragment on SearchInterface{debug{sisUrl}}fragment ItemStacksFragment on SearchInterface{itemStacks{displayMessage meta{adsBeacon{adUuid moduleInfo max_ads}query stackId stackType title layoutEnum totalItemCount totalItemCountDisplay viewAllParams{query cat_id sort facet affinityOverride recall_set min_price max_price}}itemsV2{...ItemFragment...InGridMarqueeAdFragment}}}fragment ItemFragment on Product{__typename id usItemId fitmentLabel name checkStoreAvailabilityATC seeShippingEligibility brand type shortDescription imageInfo{...ProductImageInfoFragment}canonicalUrl externalInfo{url}category{path{name url}}badges{flags{...on BaseBadge{key text type id}}tags{...on BaseBadge{key text type}}}classType averageRating numberOfReviews esrb mediaRating salesUnitType sellerId sellerName hasSellerBadge availabilityStatusV2{display value}productLocation{displayValue aisle{zone aisle}}badge{type dynamicDisplayName}fulfillmentSpeed offerId preOrder{...PreorderFragment}priceInfo{...ProductPriceInfoFragment}variantCriteria{...VariantCriteriaFragment}fulfillmentBadge fulfillmentTitle fulfillmentType brand manufacturerName showAtc sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}showOptions}fragment ProductImageInfoFragment on ProductImageInfo{thumbnailUrl}fragment ProductPriceInfoFragment on ProductPriceInfo{priceRange{minPrice maxPrice}currentPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}wasPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}unitPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}listPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}shipPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}subscriptionPrice{priceString subscriptionString}priceDisplayCodes{priceDisplayCondition finalCostByWeight}}fragment PreorderFragment on PreOrder{isPreOrder preOrderMessage preOrderStreetDateMessage}fragment ProductPriceFragment on ProductPrice{price priceString}fragment VariantCriteriaFragment on VariantCriterion{name type id isVariantTypeSwatch variantList{id images name rank swatchImageUrl availabilityStatus products selectedProduct{canonicalUrl usItemId}}}fragment InGridMarqueeAdFragment on MarqueePlaceholder{__typename type moduleLocation lazy}fragment PageMetaDataFragment on SearchInterface{pageMetadata{storeSelectionHeader{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}title canonical description location{addressId}}}fragment PaginationFragment on SearchInterface{paginationV2{maxPage pageProperties}}fragment RequestContextFragment on SearchInterface{requestContext{vertical isFitmentFilterQueryApplied searchMatchType categories{id name}}}fragment ErrorResponse on SearchInterface{errorResponse{correlationId source errors{errorType statusCode statusMsg source}}}fragment PillsModuleFragment on PillsSearchInterface{title url image:imageV1{src alt}baseSeoURL}fragment BannerModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchBannerConfigs{moduleType viewConfig{title image imageAlt displayName description url urlAlt appStoreLink appStoreLinkAlt playStoreLink playStoreLinkAlt}}fragment PopularInModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPopularInBrowseConfigs{seoBrowseRelmData(id:$catId){relm{id name url}}}fragment CopyBlockModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWCopyBlockConfigs{copyBlock(id:$catId){cwc}}fragment FacetFragment on Facet{name type layout min max selectedMin selectedMax unboundedMax stepSize values{id name description type itemCount isSelected baseSeoURL}}fragment FitmentFragment on Fitments{partTypeIDs result{status formId position quantityTitle extendedAttributes{...FitmentFieldFragment}labels{...LabelFragment}resultSubTitle}labels{...LabelFragment}savedVehicle{vehicleYear{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleMake{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleModel{...VehicleFieldFragment}additionalAttributes{...VehicleFieldFragment}}fitmentFields{...VehicleFieldFragment}fitmentForms{id fields{...FitmentFieldFragment}title labels{...LabelFragment}}}fragment LabelFragment on FitmentLabels{ctas{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}messages{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}links{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}images{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}}fragment FitmentLabelEntityFragment on FitmentLabelEntity{id label}fragment VehicleFieldFragment on FitmentVehicleField{id label value}fragment FitmentFieldFragment on FitmentField{id displayName value extended data{value label}dependsOn}fragment HeroPOVModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHeroPovConfigsV1{povCards{card{povStyle image{mobileImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}desktopImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}}heading{text textColor textSize}subheading{text textColor}detailsView{backgroundColor isTransparent}ctaButton{button{linkText clickThrough{value}}}logo{...TempoCommonImageFragment}links{link{linkText}}}}}fragment TempoCommonImageFragment on TempoCommonImage{src alt assetId uid clickThrough{value}}fragment InlineSearchModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWInlineSearchConfigs{headingText placeholderText}fragment MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWMarqueeDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...DisplayAdFragment}}fragment DisplayAdFragment on Ad{...AdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment AdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment AdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSkylineDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...SkylineDisplayAdFragment}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdFragment on Ad{...SkylineAdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment SkylineAdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHorizontalChipModuleConfigs{chipModuleSource:moduleSource chipModule{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}}chipModuleWithImages{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}image{alt clickThrough{type value}height src title width}}}",
   "variables":{
      "id":"",
      "affinityOverride":"default",
      "dealsId":"",
      "query":"",
      "page":1,
      "prg":"desktop",
      "catId":"3920",
      "facet":"",
      "sort":"best_seller",
      "rawFacet":"",
      "seoPath":"",
      "ps":40,
      "ptss":"",
      "trsp":"",
      "beShelfId":"",
      "recall_set":"",
      "module_search":"",
      "min_price":"",
      "max_price":"",
      "storeSlotBooked":"",
      "additionalQueryParams":None,
      "fitmentFieldParams":None,
      "fitmentSearchParams":{
         "id":"",
         "affinityOverride":"default",
         "dealsId":"",
         "query":"",
         "page":1,
         "prg":"desktop",
         "catId":"3920",
         "facet":"",
         "sort":"best_seller",
         "rawFacet":"",
         "seoPath":"",
         "ps":40,
         "ptss":"",
         "trsp":"",
         "beShelfId":"",
         "recall_set":"",
         "module_search":"",
         "min_price":"",
         "max_price":"",
         "storeSlotBooked":"",
         "additionalQueryParams":None,
         "cat_id":"3920",
         "_be_shelf_id":""
      },
      "fetchMarquee":True,
      "fetchSkyline":True,
      "fetchSbaTop":False
   }

}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'wm_mp': 'true',
    'wm_page_url': 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/books/3920?sort=best_seller&affinityOverride=default',
    'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g',
    'x-apollo-operation-name': 'Browse',
    'x-enable-server-timing': '1',
    'x-latency-trace': '1',
    'x-o-ccm': 'server',
    'x-o-correlation-id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g',
    'x-o-gql-query': 'query Browse',
    'x-o-market': 'us',
    'x-o-platform': 'rweb',
    'x-o-platform-version': 'main-176-e8acb5',
    'x-o-segment': 'oaoh'
    }


params= {

  "affinityOverride": "default",
    "page": "1",
    "prg": "desktop",
    "catId": "3920",
    "sort": "best_seller",
    "ps": "40",
    "fetchMarquee": "true",
    "fetchSkyline": "true",
    "fetchSbaTop": "false"}





for i in range(1,25,1):
    params['maxPage']=i
    api_url='https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/browse'
    resp = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,params=params)
    r=resp.json()
    print(r)
    # items = r['data']['search']['searchResult']['itemStacks'][0]['itemsV2']
    # for item in items:
    #     price = item['priceInfo']['currentPrice']['price']
    #     print(price)
```

the code above produce a json that includes the product url like below

```
{   
...
'canonicalUrl': '/ip/Rainbow-Watercolors-Gift-Wrapping-Papers-6-Sheets-High-Quality-24-X-18-Inch-Wrapping-Paper-Paperback/192742217?athbdg=L1600',
...
}
```

so the producturl is

```
https://www.walmart.com/ + canonicalUrl
```

How can I get the json response for the product url (i.e. includes product description and all the thumbnail pics) by modifying the code above

Update

I was able to get the json reponse of the product search result from the code i posted. what i needed is how can I go deeper to get each unique product page and get the json response. The product information from the search result is limited but there is more data on the respective product page.

Comment: Not sure I understand. `https://www.walmart.com/ + canonicalUrl` returns HTML, not JSON

Comment: by making a http request to the product url, then scrape its result (e.g.: use html/xml parser)

Comment: Thanks for your edit that is exactly what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296782/14460824) is doing, added a full example and also a solution for how to iterate the results, to get a closer look.  Don't let votes deter you from trying, the quality of the content of the answers should count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** *Be aware that this thoughts won't be bulletproofed and respect the website with its terms and conditions*

Imported also time for some delay and scrape in a more or less gentle way:

```
import json, requests, time
```

... your data and params (demo --> "query":"rainbow")

Starting from position of your for loop, just prepended `baseUrl` to concat with `canonicalUrl` and `results` to keep the scraped results:

```
baseUrl = 'https://www.walmart.com/'
results = []

# limited to 1 page for demo, change if you like
for i in range(1,2):
    params['maxPage']=i
    api_url='https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/search'
    
    resp = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,params=params)
    r=resp.json()

    items = r['data']['search']['searchResult']['itemStacks'][0]['itemsV2']
```

Requesting all products from search page - Limited to a slice of [:5] results for demo, pop if you want all results:

```
    for item in items[:5]:
        res = requests.get(f'{baseUrl}{item["canonicalUrl"]}',headers=headers)
        html = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
```

Extracting the `json` as text from product detail page html by selecting the first script with attribute type equals "application/ld+json" and load(s) it with `json.loads()`:

```
        jsonData = json.loads(html.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text)
```

Scraping the image urls from html and appending them to `jsonData`, cause they are not included in original json, just the main image:

```
        jsonData['imagesFullsize']=[i['src'].split('?')[0] for i in html.select('button > img')]
        jsonData['imagesThumbnail']=[i['src'] for i in html.select('button > img')]
```

Appending whole `jsonData` to the result list outside the for loop:

```
        results.append(jsonData)
        # some delay to be gentle
        time.sleep(5)

results
```

#### Example

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data= {'query': 'query Browse( $query:String $page:Int $prg:Prg! $facet:String $sort:Sort $catId:String! $max_price:String $min_price:String $module_search:String $affinityOverride:AffinityOverride $ps:Int $ptss:String $beShelfId:String $fitmentFieldParams:JSON ={}$fitmentSearchParams:JSON ={}$rawFacet:String $seoPath:String $trsp:String $fetchMarquee:Boolean! $fetchSkyline:Boolean! $additionalQueryParams:JSON ={}){search( query:$query page:$page prg:$prg facet:$facet sort:$sort cat_id:$catId max_price:$max_price min_price:$min_price module_search:$module_search affinityOverride:$affinityOverride additionalQueryParams:$additionalQueryParams ps:$ps ptss:$ptss trsp:$trsp _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){query searchResult{...BrowseResultFragment}}contentLayout( channel:"WWW" pageType:"BrowsePage" tenant:"WM_GLASS" version:"v1" searchArgs:{query:$query cat_id:$catId _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId prg:$prg}){modules{...ModuleFragment configs{...on EnricherModuleConfigsV1{zoneV1}__typename...on _TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchSortFilterModuleConfigs{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPillsModuleConfigs{moduleSource pillsV2{...PillsModuleFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchFitmentModuleConfigs{fitments( fitmentSearchParams:$fitmentSearchParams fitmentFieldParams:$fitmentFieldParams ){...FitmentFragment sisFitmentResponse{...BrowseResultFragment}}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWStoreSelectionHeaderConfigs{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWBreadcrumbConfigs{_rawConfigs}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSponsoredProductCarouselConfigs{_rawConfigs}...PopularInModuleFragment...CopyBlockModuleFragment...BannerModuleFragment...HeroPOVModuleFragment...InlineSearchModuleFragment...MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchMarquee)...SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchSkyline)...HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment}}...LayoutFragment pageMetadata{location{postalCode stateOrProvinceCode city storeId}pageContext}}seoBrowseMetaData( id:$catId facets:$rawFacet path:$seoPath facet_query_param:$facet _be_shelf_id:$beShelfId ){metaTitle metaDesc metaCanon h1}}fragment BrowseResultFragment on SearchInterface{title aggregatedCount...BreadCrumbFragment...DebugFragment...ItemStacksFragment...PageMetaDataFragment...PaginationFragment...RequestContextFragment...ErrorResponse modules{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}pills{...PillsModuleFragment}}}fragment ModuleFragment on TempoModule{name version type moduleId schedule{priority}matchedTrigger{zone}}fragment LayoutFragment on ContentLayout{layouts{id layout}}fragment BreadCrumbFragment on SearchInterface{breadCrumb{id name url}}fragment DebugFragment on SearchInterface{debug{sisUrl}}fragment ItemStacksFragment on SearchInterface{itemStacks{displayMessage meta{adsBeacon{adUuid moduleInfo max_ads}query stackId stackType title layoutEnum totalItemCount totalItemCountDisplay viewAllParams{query cat_id sort facet affinityOverride recall_set min_price max_price}}itemsV2{...ItemFragment...InGridMarqueeAdFragment}}}fragment ItemFragment on Product{__typename id usItemId fitmentLabel name checkStoreAvailabilityATC seeShippingEligibility brand type shortDescription imageInfo{...ProductImageInfoFragment}canonicalUrl externalInfo{url}category{path{name url}}badges{flags{...on BaseBadge{key text type id}}tags{...on BaseBadge{key text type}}}classType averageRating numberOfReviews esrb mediaRating salesUnitType sellerId sellerName hasSellerBadge availabilityStatusV2{display value}productLocation{displayValue aisle{zone aisle}}badge{type dynamicDisplayName}fulfillmentSpeed offerId preOrder{...PreorderFragment}priceInfo{...ProductPriceInfoFragment}variantCriteria{...VariantCriteriaFragment}fulfillmentBadge fulfillmentTitle fulfillmentType brand manufacturerName showAtc sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}showOptions}fragment ProductImageInfoFragment on ProductImageInfo{thumbnailUrl}fragment ProductPriceInfoFragment on ProductPriceInfo{priceRange{minPrice maxPrice}currentPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}wasPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}unitPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}listPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}shipPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}subscriptionPrice{priceString subscriptionString}priceDisplayCodes{priceDisplayCondition finalCostByWeight}}fragment PreorderFragment on PreOrder{isPreOrder preOrderMessage preOrderStreetDateMessage}fragment ProductPriceFragment on ProductPrice{price priceString}fragment VariantCriteriaFragment on VariantCriterion{name type id isVariantTypeSwatch variantList{id images name rank swatchImageUrl availabilityStatus products selectedProduct{canonicalUrl usItemId}}}fragment InGridMarqueeAdFragment on MarqueePlaceholder{__typename type moduleLocation lazy}fragment PageMetaDataFragment on SearchInterface{pageMetadata{storeSelectionHeader{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}title canonical description location{addressId}}}fragment PaginationFragment on SearchInterface{paginationV2{maxPage pageProperties}}fragment RequestContextFragment on SearchInterface{requestContext{vertical isFitmentFilterQueryApplied searchMatchType categories{id name}}}fragment ErrorResponse on SearchInterface{errorResponse{correlationId source errors{errorType statusCode statusMsg source}}}fragment PillsModuleFragment on PillsSearchInterface{title url image:imageV1{src alt}baseSeoURL}fragment BannerModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchBannerConfigs{moduleType viewConfig{title image imageAlt displayName description url urlAlt appStoreLink appStoreLinkAlt playStoreLink playStoreLinkAlt}}fragment PopularInModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPopularInBrowseConfigs{seoBrowseRelmData(id:$catId){relm{id name url}}}fragment CopyBlockModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWCopyBlockConfigs{copyBlock(id:$catId){cwc}}fragment FacetFragment on Facet{name type layout min max selectedMin selectedMax unboundedMax stepSize values{id name description type itemCount isSelected baseSeoURL}}fragment FitmentFragment on Fitments{partTypeIDs result{status formId position quantityTitle extendedAttributes{...FitmentFieldFragment}labels{...LabelFragment}resultSubTitle}labels{...LabelFragment}savedVehicle{vehicleYear{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleMake{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleModel{...VehicleFieldFragment}additionalAttributes{...VehicleFieldFragment}}fitmentFields{...VehicleFieldFragment}fitmentForms{id fields{...FitmentFieldFragment}title labels{...LabelFragment}}}fragment LabelFragment on FitmentLabels{ctas{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}messages{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}links{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}images{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}}fragment FitmentLabelEntityFragment on FitmentLabelEntity{id label}fragment VehicleFieldFragment on FitmentVehicleField{id label value}fragment FitmentFieldFragment on FitmentField{id displayName value extended data{value label}dependsOn}fragment HeroPOVModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHeroPovConfigsV1{povCards{card{povStyle image{mobileImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}desktopImage{...TempoCommonImageFragment}}heading{text textColor textSize}subheading{text textColor}detailsView{backgroundColor isTransparent}ctaButton{button{linkText clickThrough{value}}}logo{...TempoCommonImageFragment}links{link{linkText}}}}}fragment TempoCommonImageFragment on TempoCommonImage{src alt assetId uid clickThrough{value}}fragment InlineSearchModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWInlineSearchConfigs{headingText placeholderText}fragment MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWMarqueeDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...DisplayAdFragment}}fragment DisplayAdFragment on Ad{...AdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment AdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment AdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSkylineDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...SkylineDisplayAdFragment}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdFragment on Ad{...SkylineAdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment SkylineAdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHorizontalChipModuleConfigs{chipModuleSource:moduleSource chipModule{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}}chipModuleWithImages{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}image{alt clickThrough{type value}height src title width}}}', 'variables': {'id': '', 'affinityOverride': 'default', 'dealsId': '', 'query': 'rainbow', 'page': 1, 'prg': 'desktop', 'catId': '3920', 'facet': '', 'sort': 'best_seller', 'rawFacet': '', 'seoPath': '', 'ps': 40, 'ptss': '', 'trsp': '', 'beShelfId': '', 'recall_set': '', 'module_search': '', 'min_price': '', 'max_price': '', 'storeSlotBooked': '', 'additionalQueryParams': None, 'fitmentFieldParams': None, 'fitmentSearchParams': {'id': '', 'affinityOverride': 'default', 'dealsId': '', 'query': '', 'page': 1, 'prg': 'desktop', 'catId': '3920', 'facet': '', 'sort': 'best_seller', 'rawFacet': '', 'seoPath': '', 'ps': 40, 'ptss': '', 'trsp': '', 'beShelfId': '', 'recall_set': '', 'module_search': '', 'min_price': '', 'max_price': '', 'storeSlotBooked': '', 'additionalQueryParams': None, 'cat_id': '3920', '_be_shelf_id': ''}, 'fetchMarquee': True, 'fetchSkyline': True, 'fetchSbaTop': False}}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'wm_mp': 'true', 'wm_page_url': 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/books/3920?sort=best_seller&affinityOverride=default', 'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g', 'x-apollo-operation-name': 'Browse', 'x-enable-server-timing': '1', 'x-latency-trace': '1', 'x-o-ccm': 'server', 'x-o-correlation-id': 'FWpup9KEKUrLFOY68gppqfprABL16K6qE76g', 'x-o-gql-query': 'query Browse', 'x-o-market': 'us', 'x-o-platform': 'rweb', 'x-o-platform-version': 'main-176-e8acb5', 'x-o-segment': 'oaoh'}

params= {'affinityOverride': 'default', 'page': '1', 'prg': 'desktop', 'catId': '3920', 'sort': 'best_seller', 'ps': '40', 'fetchMarquee': 'true', 'fetchSkyline': 'true', 'fetchSbaTop': 'false'}



baseUrl = 'https://www.walmart.com/'
results = []

# limited to 1 page for demo, change if you like
for i in range(1,2):
    params['maxPage']=i
    api_url='https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/search'

    resp = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,params=params)
    r=resp.json()

    items = r['data']['search']['searchResult']['itemStacks'][0]['itemsV2']

    for item in items:
        res = requests.get(f'{baseUrl}{item["canonicalUrl"]}',headers=headers)
        html = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")

        jsonData = json.loads(html.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text)

        jsonData['imagesFullsize']=[i['src'].split('?')[0] for i in html.select('button > img')]
        jsonData['imagesThumbnail']=[i['src'] for i in html.select('button > img')]

        results.append(jsonData)
        # some delay to be gentle
        #time.sleep(5)

results
```

#### Output

```
[{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'Product', 'image': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/212f685a-9884-4c06-ad80-436e7caa336b.a27cb29af1e6bd338936924c3174eb60.jpeg', 'name': 'Rainbow Fish: The Rainbow Fish (Board book)', 'sku': '549445', 'gtin13': None, 'description': "<p>This board book edition features the same eye-catching holographic foil stamping that helped make the original so popular. In a simple and appealing way, the brief text conveys the story's universal message about sharing, and the smaller, sturdy format is just right for the toddler set. Full-color.The award-winning book about a beautiful fish who finds friendship and happiness when he learns to share is now available in a board book edition for the youngest child.</p>", 'model': None, 'brand': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Marcus Pfister'}, 'aggregateRating': {'@type': 'AggregateRating', 'ratingValue': 4.4, 'bestRating': 5, 'reviewCount': 181}, 'offers': {'@type': 'Offer', 'url': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rainbow-Fish-The-Rainbow-Fish-Board-book-9781558585362/549445', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'price': 5.94, 'availability': 'https://schema.org/InStock', 'itemCondition': 'https://schema.org/NewCondition', 'availableDeliveryMethod': 'https://schema.org/OnSitePickup'}, 'review': [{'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'cute book for little kids', 'datePublished': 'June 12, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'we love the graphics and glittery scales on the fish.  the story is learning to share. it was cute and my daughter enjoyed it.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'DIAMOND'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'The Rainbow Fish', 'datePublished': 'November 20, 2013', 'reviewBody': 'Great story with a great message. My son bought this book for his much younger cousin because he loved this book when he was her age.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'MyThree3Sons'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Great book!', 'datePublished': 'November 1, 2020', 'reviewBody': 'We love books!! Especially when they are quality books. This board book is great, and the pictures are bright! My little one loves it so much and I love the price! If you have little ones they will definitely enjoy this book!', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'AM01'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'July 5, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'Just right for a toddlers hands.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Mickey'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Rainbow Fish shimmering scales', 'datePublished': 'June 22, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'Excellent toddler book with beautiful illustrations of shiny scales.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'missy'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Rainbow Fish Book', 'datePublished': 'March 5, 2014', 'reviewBody': "One of my favorite children's books!!", 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Steere'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Rainbow fish', 'datePublished': 'January 16, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'Classic rainbow fish book love it', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'kim'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'pocket sized.', 'datePublished': 'March 18, 2021', 'reviewBody': "kinda small for a board book. it's literally pocket sized.", 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 4, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Cate'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Terrible Lesson', 'datePublished': 'February 4, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'I dont like this book.  What are we trying to teach our kids?  That if they make themselves less beautiful, people will like them?  That if someone admires their shirt or shoes, they should give it to them?  Or worse yet, locks of their hair?  That we need to buy friendship?  That having friends is more important than anything else, including self-worth?  Whatever happened to liking someone just the way they are?', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 2, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Patricia'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Skip this one!', 'datePublished': 'March 23, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'Not a great message for kids.  Give away your shiny scales and then you will have friends.  I would call those false friends.  Grandma says no to this one.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Mary'}}], 'imagesFullsize': ['https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/212f685a-9884-4c06-ad80-436e7caa336b.a27cb29af1e6bd338936924c3174eb60.jpeg', 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/84251155-1e3c-4d2b-8c49-a012007aa77b_1.82df42bd1a795bde9359aeecdab3396b.jpeg'], 'imagesThumbnail': ['https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/212f685a-9884-4c06-ad80-436e7caa336b.a27cb29af1e6bd338936924c3174eb60.jpeg?odnHeight=80&odnWidth=80&odnBg=FFFFFF', 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/84251155-1e3c-4d2b-8c49-a012007aa77b_1.82df42bd1a795bde9359aeecdab3396b.jpeg?odnHeight=80&odnWidth=80&odnBg=FFFFFF']}, {'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'Product', 'image': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e138cc0a-bc01-4bec-b92f-a38e2ba43059.33994c2503fb3885845815d10114cae1.jpeg', 'name': 'Origami Paper 200 Sheets Rainbow Colors 6" (15 CM) : Tuttle Origami Paper: High-Quality Origami Sheets Printed with 12 Different Colors: Instructions for 8 Projects Included', 'sku': '55746570', 'gtin13': None, 'description': '<b>This origami pack contains 200 high-quality origami sheets printed with colorful and bright rainbow colors.</b> <p>The rainbow papers were chosen to enhance the creative work of origami artists and paper crafters. The pack contains 12 different colors unique to this pack, and all of the papers are printed in coordinating colors on the reverse to provide aesthetically pleasing combinations in origami models that show both the front and back of the papers. </p><p><b>This origami paper pack includes: </b> </p><ul><li> 200 sheets of high-quality origami paper</li><li> Vibrant and bright colors</li><li> Double-sided color</li><li>6 x 6 inch (15 cm) squares</li><li> Instructions for 8 easy original projects</li></ul>', 'model': None, 'brand': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Tuttle Publishing'}, 'aggregateRating': {'@type': 'AggregateRating', 'ratingValue': 4.5, 'bestRating': 5, 'reviewCount': 12}, 'offers': {'@type': 'Offer', 'url': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Origami-Paper-200-Sheets-Rainbow-Colors-6-15-CM-Tuttle-Paper-High-Quality-Printed-12-Different-Colors-Instructions-8-Projects-Included-9780804847186/55746570', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'price': 7.64, 'availability': 'https://schema.org/InStock', 'itemCondition': 'https://schema.org/NewCondition', 'availableDeliveryMethod': 'https://schema.org/OnSitePickup'}, 'review': [{'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'March 18, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'Delivered quickly.  Item is just as it was described', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Donna'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'May 7, 2020', 'reviewBody': "Beautiful paper. Delivered unbelievably fast. Worked perfect for my daughter's project.", 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Opel'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'April 19, 2020', 'reviewBody': 'Beautiful colors and the right amount of paper for what I pay for. My daughter love it!', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Eimmy'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Paper for squares', 'datePublished': 'January 26, 2019', 'reviewBody': 'This paper is very colorful and easy to fold. Perfectly square.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'CraneMan'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Great item', 'datePublished': 'May 13, 2020', 'reviewBody': 'Grandchildren loved the activity.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Shelley'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': 'Good paper bad delivery', 'datePublished': 'October 13, 2021', 'reviewBody': 'I live in Apt. My package was not left at the door, nor in the mailbox!  But put it on the mailbox.', 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': None}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'February 18, 2021', 'reviewBody': None, 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Asheley'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'August 27, 2020', 'reviewBody': None, 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'Ididnotorderedthis'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'September 14, 2020', 'reviewBody': None, 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'David'}}, {'@type': 'Review', 'name': None, 'datePublished': 'October 22, 2020', 'reviewBody': None, 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'worstRating': 1, 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRating': 5}, 'author': {'@type': 'Thing', 'name': 'leslie'}}], 'imagesFullsize': ['https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e138cc0a-bc01-4bec-b92f-a38e2ba43059.33994c2503fb3885845815d10114cae1.jpeg', 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/290f36c3-2abe-4cea-b555-a123e18acd84.6969607693fe04e413c9100c85af9cc3.jpeg'], 'imagesThumbnail': ['https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e138cc0a-bc01-4bec-b92f-a38e2ba43059.33994c2503fb3885845815d10114cae1.jpeg?odnHeight=80&odnWidth=80&odnBg=FFFFFF', 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/290f36c3-2abe-4cea-b555-a123e18acd84.6969607693fe04e413c9100c85af9cc3.jpeg?odnHeight=80&odnWidth=80&odnBg=FFFFFF']}, ...]
```

You could simply iterate over results to print some of that information:

```
for e in results:
    print(f"""
    name:{e['name']}
    sku:{e['sku']}
    brand:{e['brand']['name']} 
    price:{e['offers']['price']}
    rating:{e['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']}...
    imagesFullsize:{e['imagesFullsize']}
    imagesThumbnail:{e['imagesThumbnail']}
    ...
    """)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `products` as search result keyword. You can see it in params(query string parameters) as key value pairs as "query": "products" or in headers or in search_url and `extract data following each product url which is called canonicalUrl` and I got hidden api calls json resonse as post method. I extract data items as canonicalUrl,thumbnailUrl,shortDescription. Now you can grab more data according to your need. The canonicalUrls are relative urls and  I've converted them into absolute urls and made pagination following maxPage.

## Script:

```
#search_url = https://www.walmart.com/search?q=products&page=2&affinityOverride=store_led
import requests
import json

body = {
   "query":"query Search( $query:String $page:Int $prg:Prg! $facet:String $sort:Sort = best_match $catId:String $max_price:String $min_price:String $spelling:Boolean = true $affinityOverride:AffinityOverride $storeSlotBooked:String $ps:Int $ptss:String $recall_set:String $fitmentFieldParams:JSON ={}$fitmentSearchParams:JSON ={}$fetchMarquee:Boolean! $trsp:String $fetchSkyline:Boolean! $fetchSbaTop:Boolean! $additionalQueryParams:JSON ={}){search( query:$query page:$page prg:$prg facet:$facet sort:$sort cat_id:$catId max_price:$max_price min_price:$min_price spelling:$spelling affinityOverride:$affinityOverride storeSlotBooked:$storeSlotBooked ps:$ps ptss:$ptss recall_set:$recall_set trsp:$trsp additionalQueryParams:$additionalQueryParams ){query searchResult{...SearchResultFragment}}contentLayout( channel:\"WWW\" pageType:\"SearchPage\" tenant:\"WM_GLASS\" searchArgs:{query:$query cat_id:$catId prg:$prg}){modules{...ModuleFragment configs{...SearchNonItemFragment __typename...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSponsoredProductCarouselConfigs{_rawConfigs}...on _TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchSortFilterModuleConfigs{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}}...on _TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchGuidedNavModuleConfigs{guidedNavigation{...GuidedNavFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWPillsModuleConfigs{moduleSource pillsV2{...PillsModuleFragment}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchFitmentModuleConfigs{fitments( fitmentSearchParams:$fitmentSearchParams fitmentFieldParams:$fitmentFieldParams ){...FitmentFragment sisFitmentResponse{...SearchResultFragment}}}...on TempoWM_GLASSWWWStoreSelectionHeaderConfigs{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}...BrandAmplifierAdConfigs @include(if:$fetchSbaTop)...BannerModuleFragment...MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchMarquee)...SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment @include(if:$fetchSkyline)...HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment}}...LayoutFragment pageMetadata{location{postalCode stateOrProvinceCode city storeId}pageContext}}}fragment SearchResultFragment on SearchInterface{title aggregatedCount...BreadCrumbFragment...DebugFragment...ItemStacksFragment...PageMetaDataFragment...PaginationFragment...SpellingFragment...RequestContextFragment...ErrorResponse modules{facetsV1{...FacetFragment}guidedNavigation{...GuidedNavFragment}guidedNavigationV2{...PillsModuleFragment}pills{...PillsModuleFragment}spellCheck{title subTitle urlLinkText url}}}fragment ModuleFragment on TempoModule{name version type moduleId schedule{priority}matchedTrigger{zone}}fragment LayoutFragment on ContentLayout{layouts{id layout}}fragment BreadCrumbFragment on SearchInterface{breadCrumb{id name url}}fragment DebugFragment on SearchInterface{debug{sisUrl}}fragment ItemStacksFragment on SearchInterface{itemStacks{displayMessage meta{adsBeacon{adUuid moduleInfo max_ads}query stackId stackType title layoutEnum totalItemCount totalItemCountDisplay viewAllParams{query cat_id sort facet affinityOverride recall_set min_price max_price}}itemsV2{...ItemFragment...InGridMarqueeAdFragment}}}fragment ItemFragment on Product{__typename id usItemId fitmentLabel name checkStoreAvailabilityATC seeShippingEligibility brand type shortDescription imageInfo{...ProductImageInfoFragment}canonicalUrl externalInfo{url}category{path{name url}}badges{flags{...on BaseBadge{key text type id}}tags{...on BaseBadge{key text type}}}classType averageRating numberOfReviews esrb mediaRating salesUnitType sellerId sellerName hasSellerBadge availabilityStatusV2{display value}productLocation{displayValue aisle{zone aisle}}badge{type dynamicDisplayName}fulfillmentSpeed offerId preOrder{...PreorderFragment}priceInfo{...ProductPriceInfoFragment}variantCriteria{...VariantCriteriaFragment}fulfillmentBadge fulfillmentTitle fulfillmentType brand manufacturerName showAtc sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}showOptions}fragment ProductImageInfoFragment on ProductImageInfo{thumbnailUrl}fragment ProductPriceInfoFragment on ProductPriceInfo{priceRange{minPrice maxPrice}currentPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}wasPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}unitPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}listPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}shipPrice{...ProductPriceFragment}subscriptionPrice{priceString subscriptionString}priceDisplayCodes{priceDisplayCondition finalCostByWeight}}fragment PreorderFragment on PreOrder{isPreOrder preOrderMessage preOrderStreetDateMessage}fragment ProductPriceFragment on ProductPrice{price priceString}fragment VariantCriteriaFragment on VariantCriterion{name type id isVariantTypeSwatch variantList{id images name rank swatchImageUrl availabilityStatus products selectedProduct{canonicalUrl usItemId}}}fragment InGridMarqueeAdFragment on MarqueePlaceholder{__typename type moduleLocation lazy}fragment PageMetaDataFragment on SearchInterface{pageMetadata{storeSelectionHeader{fulfillmentMethodLabel storeDislayName}title canonical description location{addressId}}}fragment PaginationFragment on SearchInterface{paginationV2{maxPage pageProperties}}fragment SpellingFragment on SearchInterface{spelling{correctedTerm}}fragment RequestContextFragment on SearchInterface{requestContext{vertical isFitmentFilterQueryApplied searchMatchType categories{id name}}}fragment ErrorResponse on SearchInterface{errorResponse{correlationId source errors{errorType statusCode statusMsg source}}}fragment GuidedNavFragment on GuidedNavigationSearchInterface{title url}fragment PillsModuleFragment on PillsSearchInterface{title url image:imageV1{src alt}baseSeoURL}fragment BannerModuleFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchBannerConfigs{moduleType viewConfig{title image imageAlt displayName description url urlAlt appStoreLink appStoreLinkAlt playStoreLink playStoreLinkAlt}}fragment FacetFragment on Facet{name type layout min max selectedMin selectedMax unboundedMax stepSize values{id name description type itemCount isSelected baseSeoURL}}fragment FitmentFragment on Fitments{partTypeIDs result{status formId position quantityTitle extendedAttributes{...FitmentFieldFragment}labels{...LabelFragment}resultSubTitle}labels{...LabelFragment}savedVehicle{vehicleYear{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleMake{...VehicleFieldFragment}vehicleModel{...VehicleFieldFragment}additionalAttributes{...VehicleFieldFragment}}fitmentFields{...VehicleFieldFragment}fitmentForms{id fields{...FitmentFieldFragment}title labels{...LabelFragment}}}fragment LabelFragment on FitmentLabels{ctas{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}messages{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}links{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}images{...FitmentLabelEntityFragment}}fragment FitmentLabelEntityFragment on FitmentLabelEntity{id label}fragment VehicleFieldFragment on FitmentVehicleField{id label value}fragment FitmentFieldFragment on FitmentField{id displayName value extended data{value label}dependsOn}fragment MarqueeDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWMarqueeDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...DisplayAdFragment}}fragment DisplayAdFragment on Ad{...AdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment AdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment AdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSkylineDisplayAdConfigs{_rawConfigs ad{...SkylineDisplayAdFragment}}fragment SkylineDisplayAdFragment on Ad{...SkylineAdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment}}}fragment SkylineAdFragment on Ad{status moduleType platform pageId pageType storeId stateCode zipCode pageContext moduleConfigs adsContext adRequestComposite}fragment SkylineAdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment BrandAmplifierAdConfigs on TempoWM_GLASSWWWBrandAmplifierAdConfigs{_rawConfigs moduleLocation ad{...SponsoredBrandsAdFragment}}fragment SponsoredBrandsAdFragment on Ad{...AdFragment adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataSponsoredBrandsFragment}}}fragment AdDataSponsoredBrandsFragment on AdData{...on SponsoredBrands{adUuid adExpInfo moduleInfo brands{logo{featuredHeadline featuredImage featuredImageName featuredUrl logoClickTrackUrl}products{...ProductFragment}}}}fragment ProductFragment on Product{usItemId offerId badges{flags{...on BaseBadge{key text type id}}labels{key text}tags{key text}}priceInfo{priceDisplayCodes{rollback reducedPrice eligibleForAssociateDiscount clearance strikethrough submapType priceDisplayCondition unitOfMeasure pricePerUnitUom}currentPrice{price priceString}wasPrice{price priceString}priceRange{minPrice maxPrice priceString}unitPrice{price priceString}}showOptions sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}canonicalUrl numberOfReviews averageRating availabilityStatus imageInfo{thumbnailUrl allImages{id url}}name fulfillmentBadge classType type showAtc p13nData{predictedQuantity flags{PREVIOUSLY_PURCHASED{text}CUSTOMERS_PICK{text}}labels{PREVIOUSLY_PURCHASED{text}CUSTOMERS_PICK{text}}}}fragment SearchNonItemFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWSearchNonItemConfigs{title subTitle urlLinkText url}fragment HorizontalChipModuleConfigsFragment on TempoWM_GLASSWWWHorizontalChipModuleConfigs{chipModuleSource:moduleSource chipModule{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}}chipModuleWithImages{title url{linkText title clickThrough{type value}}image{alt clickThrough{type value}height src title width}}}",
   "variables":{
      "id":"",
      "affinityOverride":"store_led",
      "dealsId":"",
      "query":"products",
      "page":1,
      "prg":"desktop",
      "catId":"",
      "facet":"",
      "sort":"best_match",
      "rawFacet":"",
      "seoPath":"",
      "ps":40,
      "ptss":"",
      "trsp":"",
      "beShelfId":"",
      "recall_set":"",
      "module_search":"",
      "min_price":"",
      "max_price":"",
      "storeSlotBooked":"",
      "additionalQueryParams":None,
      "fitmentFieldParams":None,
      "fitmentSearchParams":{
         "id":"",
         "affinityOverride":"store_led",
         "dealsId":"",
         "query":"products",
         "page":1,
         "prg":"desktop",
         "catId":"",
         "facet":"",
         "sort":"best_match",
         "rawFacet":"",
         "seoPath":"",
         "ps":40,
         "ptss":"",
         "trsp":"",
         "beShelfId":"",
         "recall_set":"",
         "module_search":"",
         "min_price":"",
         "max_price":"",
         "storeSlotBooked":"",
         "additionalQueryParams":None,
         "cat_id":"",
         "_be_shelf_id":""
      },
      "fetchMarquee":True,
      "fetchSkyline":True,
      "fetchSbaTop":True
   }
}


headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
    "wm_mp": "true",
    "wm_page_url": "https://www.walmart.com/search?q=products&affinityOverride=store_led",
    "wm_qos.correlation_id": "8RTnrq0_I8HVifb9ZLF-aiSA-VhFXxzjTke4",
    "x-apollo-operation-name": "Search",
    "x-enable-server-timing": "1",
    "x-latency-trace": "1",
    "x-o-ccm": "server",
    "x-o-correlation-id": "8RTnrq0_I8HVifb9ZLF-aiSA-VhFXxzjTke4",
    "x-o-gql-query": "query Search",
    "x-o-market": "us",
    "x-o-platform": "rweb",
    "x-o-platform-version": "main-176-348925",
    "x-o-segment": "oaoh"
    }
params= {
    "affinityOverride": "store_led",
    "query": "products",
    "page": "1",
    "prg": "desktop",
    "sort": "best_match",
    "ps": "40",
    "fetchMarquee": "true",
    "fetchSkyline": "true",
    "fetchSbaTop": "true",
    }


for i in range(1,26,1):
    print(i)
    params['maxPage']=i
    api_url = "https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/search"
    r = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
    
    response = r.json()['data']['search']['searchResult']['itemStacks'][0]['itemsV2']
    #print(response)


    for resp in response:     
        canonicalUrl_rel_url = resp['canonicalUrl']
        canonicalUrl_abs_url = f'https://www.walmart.com{canonicalUrl_rel_url}'
        #print(canonicalUrl_abs_url)
        thumbnailUrl=resp['imageInfo']['thumbnailUrl']
        #print(thumbnailUrl)
        shortDescription=resp['shortDescription']

        print('canonicalUrl :' +str(canonicalUrl_abs_url),'thumbnailUrl: ' + str(thumbnailUrl),'shortDescription: ' +str(shortDescription), sep = '\n')
```

## Output

25th page

```
25
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Outdoor-Products-Traverse-25-Ltr-Backpack-Black-Unisex/50109913
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/5930259f-93e6-4f55-a55c-8b31d0f26788_1.28b726e073876f2ec3576016cbd4c5d0.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>Front pocket organizer</li><li>Sternum strap</li><li>Foam Padded Back</li><li>Top Carry Handle</li><li>Secondary compartment with organizer</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Harris-Products-Group-30-Vinegar-Concentrate-1-Gallon-All-Purpose-Cleaner/247531021
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/0816ab37-ca97-40b5-b549-d205be0edac8.681ba25e7bae43e841440edad16c566b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>Hundreds of home and garden uses</li><li>6X stronger than standard Vinegars</li><li>Contains no bleach, ammonia, or harmful chemicals</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/The-Relief-Products-RedEye-Relief-Eye-Drops-33-fl-oz/805948778
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b03ba419-4704-469b-b15a-aa0dc0d54d88.7e81daea61ca4834245f7a57da0b831c.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: TRP Sterile Eye Drops RedEye Relief
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Fairchase-Products-13325-4-oz-Nosejammer-Aerosol-Field-Spray/605427089?athbdg=L1700
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/88338354-c5d2-4a35-b4ca-040fcf552431.d2b367ba7dedefde4e6c24ccf3cabf2b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: Fairchase Products 13325 4 oz Nosejammer Aerosol Field Spray
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Happy-Home-Pet-Products-Dog-Water-Bottle-32-oz/14551175
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/5869325c-6872-48fe-b0f2-3ecb1e91efb1.e9ade714fa876d8927dd4b266728ace5.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: None
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Harris-Products-Group-Super-Size-Snake-Glue-Trap-1-Pack/780276350      
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b9446907-e52d-4aef-9771-20f20d02936f.0cd4e68951262cc3b216e10e0d3d43da.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>Extra sticky, hold snakes in place</li><li>Large surface area</li><li>Catches Rats and Mice, as well as snakes</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/PAW-Patrol-Jumbo-Coloring-Book-96-Pages/965279945
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/47340399-f6d1-463c-8892-da2821226e05.4cc27a88e836cba3a6f4f44c35127686.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: PAW Patrol Jumbo Coloring Book, 96 Pages
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Palmer-s-Olive-Oil-Formula-Gro-Therapy-8-8-oz/10311234
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/c44fae92-a72d-4109-b173-dffbb02f3040.01d72803369e9d714db57175e7b65a92.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: Palmer's Olive Oil Formula with Vitamin E Gro Therapy
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/K-N-Premium-Oil-Filter-Designed-Protect-Engine-Fits-Select-MAZDA-FORD-LINCOLN-DODGE-Vehicle-Models-See-Product-Description-Full-List-Compatible-Vehic/34771460
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/411c6916-ade8-4ee0-85a8-14934c19ce61_1.744ce8b5f4cd02115fd1b043c110bdb3.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: O/E replacement oil filters for most cars, trucks, SUV's, motorcycles, & ATV'sResin-impregnated filter media traps 99% of harmful contaminants1 In. exposed nut designed for easy oil filter
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/ChapStick-Moisturizer-Spf-15-Skin-Protectant-Lip-Balm-Tube-Original-Flavor-0-15-Oz/940344856
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/282bebda-98f5-4a4b-9e38-7694da53477c.6a119a61ff2ec8c70ec0d233ae16a988.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>America's favorite lip balm in Original Flavor</li><li>For smoother & softer lips</li><li>With SPF 15 sun protection</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Neutrogena-Fragrance-Free-Makeup-Remover-Face-Wipe-Singles-20-ct/451864259
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/72274d32-8bc7-4e70-9263-c9bfffa98425.0e3fe212e33959a5583fd213dce81336.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>Individually wrapped fragrance-free wipes</li><li>Gently removes dirt, oil & makeup from skin</li><li>Made with 100% plant-based cloth</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Olay-Regenerist-Ultra-Rich-Face-Moisturizer-Fragrance-Free-Trial-Size-0-5-Oz/807789628
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/f52c5d50-279f-40aa-b69f-a9af6a59b6c3.51f9cf1c2b688d8c5e19397fe8903351.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>INTENSE HYDRATION: This thick and creamy moisturizer instantly hydrates and visibly firms 
your skin</li><li>LUXURIOUSLY CREAMY: We've designed this formula to feel rich and creamy and melt into</li>    
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/NexSheen-Arganics-OutSmooth-This-Edge-Smoothing-Gel-8oz/46108271       
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/8a04a34f-af0d-4ff8-bebf-e45d0b5298c8.88c8f956fdeaf5c49935c916789f862f.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: "<li>Non-Greasy, Flexible Hold</li><li>Does Not Flake or Leave a White Residue</li><li>For Relaxed & Natural Hair Styles</li>"
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Neutrogena-Hydro-Boost-Hydrating-Hyaluronic-Acid-Cleansing-Gel-2-oz/621564858
thumbnailUrl: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2712c513-3c71-42f6-80f1-7f9e74ca92ad.1622e6698de6fa46120df8163e2d4074.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff
shortDescription: <li>Hydrating lightweight facial cleansing gel</li><li>Effectively lifts away dirt, oil & makeup</li><li>Contains hyaluronic acid</li>
canonicalUrl :https://www.walmart.com/ip/Disney-Frozen-2-Super-Coloring-Book-160-Pages/310688628
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the json reponse of the product search result from the code i posted. what i needed is how can I go deeper to get each unique product page and get the json response. The product information from the search result is limited but there is more data on the respective product page.

Comment: If you click on a product item then you have to bring  to an individual page along with individual url which is same as canonicalUrl meaning if you search canonicalUrl then
you have to bring  to an individual page item meaning the same thing two way. The products  listings page from where we get information of each product list and  individual page/canonicalUrl but json response is single contains full information whatever it get from api. Actually,json response has no two way to send information. Almost, all the information of individual page, you aslso will find from here json response

Comment: That's a tiny  task to remove tags from strings

Comment: All information exist in json response  and it includes description as short summary description  except detailed description which is not a major matter and you also didn't include detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

As stated you should use an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You need to select each part of the page you want to record.

Here is an example which picks out the product name from the HTML. Note
I had to look at the HTML and determine that `<h1 itemprop="name" ...>` contained the desired :

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pelonis-1500W-3-Speed-Electric-Fan-Forced-Space-Heater-PSH08F1ABB-Black/795905622?athbdg=L1600"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
product_data = {}

product_data["product_name"] = None
for h1 in soup.find_all("h1"):
    print(h1)
    if h1.get("itemprop") == "name":
        product_data["product_name"] = h1.string
else:
    print("product name not found")
```

HOWEVER it seems like walmart doesn't want people crawling their page.