# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' Running Python/Beautiful Soup for Price Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Received this error when running this web scraping python script

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
  File "C:\Users\richard\Documents\python code\chatgptcodeaz_price_test.py", line 39, in <module>
    jsonData = json.loads(nextTag.text)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ac="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"

target_url="https://www.walmart.com/ip/Mobil-1-Advanced-Full-Synthetic-Motor-Oil-5W-30-5-qt/17034372?athbdg=L1102"

headers={"Referer":"https://www.google.com","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Accept":ac,"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"}

resp = requests.get(target_url)
# print(resp.text)
# if("Robot or human" in resp.text):
#     print(True)
# else:
#     print(False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')
l=[]
obj={}

try:
    obj["price"] = soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"price"}).text.replace("Now ","")
except:
    obj["price"]=None

try:
    obj["name"] = soup.find("h1",{"itemprop":"name"}).text
except:
    obj["name"]=None

try:
    obj["rating"] = soup.find("span",{"class":"rating-number"}).text.replace("(","").replace(")","")
except:
    obj["rating"]=None

import json

nextTag = soup.find("script",{"id":"__NEXT_DATA__"})
jsonData = json.loads(nextTag.text)

Detail = jsonData['props']['pageProps']['initialData']['data']['product']['shortDescription']

try:
    obj["detail"] = Detail
except:
    obj["detail"]=None

l.append(obj)
print(l)
```

Comment: The error is that `nextTag = soup.find("script",{"id":"__NEXT_DATA__"})` does not find the `nextTag` so it is set to None. You must find another way to find it or handle separately the case where it is None

Comment: You are actually blocked by CAPTCHA, you're getting "Robot or human?" page!!!

Comment: Does this answer is an alternative? [how to get the json response for a product url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253966/how-to-get-the-json-response-for-a-product-url)